# Import CSV File to H2 before Migration

Tags: java, csv, h2, flyway

I'm trying to use Flyway to migrate an in-memory h2 database.  Creating the table works fine the traditional way, but I would also like to use h2's import csv as described [here](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv).  I can't find anything in the Flyway documentation that says this won't work.  Is this supported?

**UPDATE:**  This is the V02__createTables.sql that I'm trying to migrate.  This script is in db.migration.test and Flyway knows about the directory.  The csv file an_products.csv is also in this folder, hence being referenced by h2's CSVREAD method below.

```
CREATE TABLE an_products (
  id int(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  price double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  taxable tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  notes varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  isPercent tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  min double DEFAULT NULL,
  period char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  qty int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  cost double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
) AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('an_products.csv');
```

Comment: I've removed the useless stacktrace.  Figured I'd provide it just in case I was asked for a stacktrace.

Comment: I really want to know if this is supported by flyway or not.  I refer to an example that uses the syntax I'm using in the script that's failing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit support, nor is there a restriction. Flyway will execute all statements through JDBC. So whether this will work depends on whether H2 supports this statement through JDBC or not.

Comment: Hey Axel, thanks for your answer.  The thing is, there is a FlyWay Exception that is thrown.  As was pointed out by Jarrod, it wasn't a very useful exception, just that migration to version 02 failed.  I will update my question to include the V02__createTables.sql, which is what I'm trying to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure the relative path works, maybe FlyWay has a different working directory, maybe just make the path absolute.

Or Use a debugger and tell it to break on Exception throws, this way, you know where it occurs.